# Am trying to determine the source of a low level, low pitched "rumbling" noise that appears to only be heard inside houses in our road, any thoughts?

Tags: acoustics

I live in the Olton area within the UK. The noise can be briefly intermittent or continuous for hours and can only be heard indoors - louder at night. One neighbour has reported that his pillow vibrates at night. The local water authority have said that the noise is nothing to do with them, even though their sewers run through pipes that run under ground along the road and that they have storm tanks within the area. WE do have HS2 boring tunnels about 10 mile away, could this be the cause ?

Comment: Do you have a recording of the noise?

Comment: @ArthurPoolton Are you talking about [The Hum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hum)?

Comment: Hi Farcher & Vincent, not possible to record the noise and it is definitely NOT the world wide hum. Arthur

Comment: On the map it shows a few railway stations within a km or two, perhaps they are doing work.  Also is your house terraced or detached?  Could be that another house in the terrace has a fan or something on at night for some reason...

Comment: For those of us outside the UK who've never heard of HS2 tunnels: https://www.hs2.org.uk/building-hs2/tunnels/

Comment: What do you mean that it's not possible to record the noise? Maybe you need to try with a more sensitive microphone.

Comment: Have checked the railway - no work being carried out,. Our house is semi-detached, and the noise can be heard by other people in other houses, building work is not allowed during the night, and I don't have access to a sensitive microphone.

Comment: How close along the street is the house where the "pillow vibrates at night"?  If it were HS2 surely people closer to the tunnel would have reported it.  If it is that it'll be over in a year or so if it's any consolation, the website from @ PM 2Ring said 15 metres per day and a 3.5 mile section to do.  So it's a year unless they need two years for both tunnels.

Comment: One theory was that maybe the noise from the tunnelling was somehow reverberating along the water authority's sewer pipe network

Comment: Maybe, you need more data.  It's quite likely that it's more local.  So it's recommended that you get talking to lots of people at different distances from your house.  For example if it's only limited to your street and e.g. 100m radius, it's probably some anti-social neighbour or nearby factory.  If it's heard from other houses e.g. half a mile away, then it's louder and could be further, e.g. bigger factory HS2 etc...do different neighbours report different volumes?

Comment: ...also do you mind saying the street name, so others can look on Google maps and suggest things

Comment: I am in the process of visiting all neighbours in the immediate vicinity. I am in a residential area (ie. no nearby factories - other than Land Rover who are reported to not be doing any building work). The only way of raising the issue with a wider area will be via one of the local forums.

Comment: In answer to your query - Greswolde Road, Solihull

Comment: Ok, thanks, a  proper answer has been posted, but it's an interesting puzzle and will check out the map

Answer (score 1):

Arthur,

High frequency sound get absorbed more quickly in dense material than low frequency sound.  The fact that the noise is low frequency and can only be heard indoors suggest that it's travelled some distance underground.

However the distance could be small e.g. 10m or many km if the source is loud enough.

You've asked on a physics website, so it's best to test different theories with experiment.

The theory that it's HS2 tunnelling noise travelling along pipes is best tested like this - Try and get a record of tunnelling times from HS2 (e.g. for a particular few days) and see if it matches what you hear.

If it is the above, it seems unlikely that tunnelling so far away would always effect you, i.e. the source of the sound moves as the tunnelling progresses, presumably it wouldn't be near enough to the pipes that had a route under your house before long, in which case it'll cease to be a problem.

It's quite likely to be more local.

Here is the website for Coventry Environmental Health, they have a 'report a noise problem' link [Environmental Health](https://www.coventry.gov.uk/pollution), although you might need the Birmingham one.

Best of luck with it.

Comment: Thanks John, I will keep investigating. For information, I have contacted Solihull Council : as far as they are concerned they will only act if the source of the noise can be identified.

Comment: @ Arthur Poolton thanks for address, only other idea is that the local water authority might deal with different things and perhaps you could also enquire at the 
 https://canalrivertrust.org.uk/notices/8327-olton-reservoir-grand-union-canal 'contact us' link.  Perhaps water is sometimes pumped into the reservoir from somewhere else (as well as getting rainwater) and water board don't know the details.

Comment: @ Arthur Poolton  P.S. to check that, see if the noise is connected to the level of the reservoir or amount of rain that you've had.

Comment: Hi John, Have checked out your suggestion. The reservoir is only there to maintain the water level in the Grand Union Canal whenever it needs to be. ie. whenever a barge goes though a lock. The reservoir is fed via a small stream via a culvert. I have checked with the local Water Authority (ie. Severn Trent) if there is any pumping equipment in the culvert. Answer - No. Another thought I had was whether the water supply system may be at fault somewhere.  If you have any other divine inspiration then please let me know. Best regards Arthur

Comment: @ Arthur Poolton   It could be any equipment, perhaps make a general enquiry to them, e.g. filters or something else, but it seems from the map that it's probably connected to the pipes that may go under that street towards the reservoir.    Are you uphill from the reservoir?  When the noise is happening you could walk to where the culvert meets the reservoir and listen there too...

Comment: @ Arthur Poolton ...or perhaps the pipes to reservoir under your street mean that DIY or factory noise from up or down the road carries further than usual underground, perhaps good idea to walk around near other houses when the noise is happening to see if it's a neighbour issue...that's all the ideas at the moment, best of luck